# Python Subprocess mount returning - non zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspbian

I've successfully mounted the drive using fixed //IP/Folder /Mount/Point while providing interchangable username and password as the NAS has permissions set up which are unique to each user.

My First and Working Attempt:

```
    subprocess.check_call("sudo mount -t cifs -o username="+txtUsername.get()+",password="txtPassword.get()+" //IP/Folder /Mount/Point", shell=true)
```

However after wanting to create a more felxible program i wanted to be able to change the IP and Folder as well as the Mount Point through a config menu.

However when I try to build the command and use it with shell=true it doesn't work and returns a "non zero exit status 1" as a response from the try/except.The structure of the command returned is no different from my working attempt, however the way which i insert it is through variables.

```
    try
        password = txtPassword.get()
        username = txtUsername.get()
        localpath = mountPath
        serverAddress = ' //'+serverIP + serverPath +' '+localpath
        command =  serverAddress

        print(command)

        subprocess.check_output('sudo mount -t cifs -o username='+username+',password='+password+str(command), shell=True)

    #If try fails, caputure error type and store in variable
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print ("error Message:"+str(e))
```

**** UPDATE ****

I've done as request in turning the command into an argument after doing some research however the result is no different and still returns a "non zero exit status 1"

```
    command =  "sudo mount -t cifs -o username="+username+" password="+password + " " + serverAddress+ " " + localpath        
    print(command)

    subprocess.check_output(command.split(), shell=False)
```

Comment: Don't use `shell=True`, but use a list of arguments.

Comment: if the password contains a quote or any shell escape char, your command line is just wrong. See Daniel comment.

Comment: I have attempted to list the command as arguements and it still doesn't work, while from my understanding the shell=True seperates the command where there is whitespace which is no different to what I have done with the split command.
Also Password and username do not contain any escape chars, and if possible could you provide some guideance on Shell=False as im not entirely sure that I implemented it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried printing the command out and running it directly on the command line? Also, I'm surprised the `sudo` works unless you have no-password set. You can think about `shell=True` as being somewhat equivalent to `['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sudo mount ...']` with `shell=False`. It's almost always more reliable to use `shell=False` unless you want to use a shell feature (e.g. redirection)—but there are ways of otherwise doing that as well.

Comment: I'm using sudo to bypass the restriction on the command as it isn't running from root  but instead /home/pi/ on Raspbian, and as for the it working in command line, yes it works perfectly fine which is why i am struggling to understand where the issues lie. Another bit of informination that the command works with Shell=True untill i change the Target NAS drive address to a variable which I am using to mount the drive to a local folder. but I am unsure as to whether this is a potential reason as to why its breaking.